# Confusion on GSM, GPRS, EDGE, 3G, 4G

Tags: gsm

I'm using a smartphone.

When I turn off the cellular data or my mobile phone, I can still call and send SMS.
Does that mean in this case the mobile using GSM? How can I know if it is GSM or GPRS? And which technique is used TDMA or CDMA?

When I turn on the cellular data I see for examle 3G or 4G or LTE active.
In this case, does that mean GSM or GPRS is inactive and voice and SMS is also
sent via 3G or GSM is separately always active?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GSM and GPRS are two separate things, GSM is used for SMS texting and calls. GPRS is used for mobile data transmission over the internet (can be used for calls and texting also). GPRS, EDGE, HSDPA, 3G, 4G are mobile communication protocols, the most obvious difference is in speed and bandwith, i lined them from slowest to fastest.

Comment: in my phone one can choose 3 cellular data options. 2G, 3G and 4G. is 2G means edge or GPRS- The reason I asked this question if I disable cellular data I can still send sms and make calls. Does that mean GSM is active all the time with a seperate antenna?

Comment: one other reason I'm asking is figuring out the coding techniques like TDMA CDMA. can we say that GSM uses TDMA and FDMA and 3G data uses another technique. Im kinda stuck with jargon.

Comment: When we are using 2G, we can't call and use data transfer at the same time, 2G is the first digital mobile communication protocol after 1G, all data is transferred digitally. Data is transferred via 'data call' which uses line as a normal call, so thats the reason they cant work both at the same time. GSM uses both TDMA and FDMA.

Comment: how can I know that when I make a call if my connection is handles via CDMA FDMA or TDMA?

Comment: I think it depends on mobile phone carriers.

Comment: the thing is if i change to another subscriber by using insering sim, how can the phone adapt the new technique?

Comment: You're end-user, your device has nothing with multiplexing techniques of the carrier and how they serve their resources to their end-users. You just receive required data, thats all.

Comment: i see, i think i started to get it. just one more thing.. does 3G 4G and later cellular data techs use a separate antenna? and EDGE uses the same antenna with GSM? is that the reason you wrote that we cannot both use EDGE and voice calls/sms?

Comment: They all use the same antenna, although in different radio bands. The phone uses a configured list of networks in the SIM to search in sequence for base stations belonging to your network provider or, failing that, a suitable roaming provider.

Answer (score 1):

The GPRS radio interface uses a 52 frame multiframe, which is identical in length to the 2*26 frame traffic multiframe used by GSM.

The GPRS hyperframe can therefore either have its own ARFCN, or it can use a GSM traffic or control hyperframe ARFCN. It can do this because not all time slots in the radio block need to be used, and can be allocated to GSM instead.

Once you have located the BCCH within the cell, [it tells you the ARFC and frame number the PBCCH within the hyperframe modulo the length of a multiframe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67860213/7194773). You can then attach to the GPRS network over the PRACH channel indicated in the PBCCH. Similarly, you can attach to the GSM network over the RACH indicated in the BCCH. The BSC knows where to forward these channels, MSC or PCU. You can be connected to both networks at the same time.

EDGE is simply the use of the MCS-1–9 coding and modulation schemes on the radio interface instead of CS-1—4 defined for GPRS. It does this by using the CS-1 encoding to perform a request of EGPRS Packet Channel Request RLC message type on the PRACH, and the PDTCH assigned by the PCU will now use the assigned MCS modulation scheme, which uses different RLC/MAC headers and coding, a different L1 slot and burst format, and a different modulation scheme, either GMSK or 8-PSK depending on the MCS version selected. EDGE also encompasses ESCD which enhances the existing HSCSD (data over GSM TCHs), but this is never used.

Comment: I will add edge, umts, hspda and 4g in a second. This might turn out to be a very long answer